# How can I "merge" the content of two QVariantMap in Qt5?

Tags: c++, merge, qt5

I have two `QVariantMap` instances **A** and **B**.

In **A** I have the following strings: `[ "key1" => "Cat", "key2" => "Dog", "key3" => "Mouse" ]`.
In **B** I have the following strings: `[ "key1" => "Cat", "key4" => "Dog", "key3" => "Bison" ]`.

I want to merge them into a third `QVariantMap` instance **C** so that it contains the following:

`[ "key1" => "Cat", "key2" => "Dog", "key3" => "Bison", "key4" => "Dog" ]`.

Note how there is only one "Cat" and how "Mouse" was replaced by "Bison".

Is there a way to do this in *Qt5* without writing my own utility function to do it?

Comment: I believe that the Qt containers are compliant and
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/merge/
should work

Comment: `std::merge` doesn't unify -- `std::set_union` would, but it gives precedence to the elements in the first range, not the second (and anyhow they're not quite usable with map iterators).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 5.15, Qt provides [an `insert` overload](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#insert-2) taking another `QMap` as parameter, which inserts all key/value pairs from the other map into the original map, overwriting existing keys:

```
    QVariantMap A;
    QVariantMap B;

    A.insert("key1", "Cat");
    A.insert("key2", "Dog");
    A.insert("key3", "Mouse");

    B.insert("key1", "Cat");
    B.insert("key4", "Dog");
    B.insert("key3", "Bison");

    QVariantMap C(A);
    C.insert(B);

    // C now holds the combined keys&values of A & B;
    // for keys existing in both A and B, the values from B are taken!
```

Answer (score 3):

```
QVariantMap A;
QVariantMap B;
QVariantMap C;
A.insert("key1", "Cat");
A.insert("key2", "Dog");
A.insert("key3", "Mouse");

B.insert("key1", "Cat");
B.insert("key4", "Dog");
B.insert("key3", "Bison");

//Merge A and B
C = A.unite(B);
//C.value("key1") = "Cat" 
//C.value("key3") = "Bison"
//C.values("key3") = {"Bison", "Mouse"}
//C.values("key1") = {"Cat", "Cat"}
//Note: A = C as well. If you don't want to change the value of A, then assign a temporary value to A or create a copy of A

//Method 1: Create a copy of A
QVariantMap ACopy = A;
C = ACopy.unite(B);

//Method 2: Create a temporary variable that hold A value:
QVariantMap ATemp = A;
C = A.unite(B);
A = ATemp;
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation to the code? It would make for a better answer

Comment: Updated with comment. Hope this make it a little more clear.

Comment: From what I could gather looking at the [documentation of QMap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html), this does not do what OP wants:  It will not merge entries with the same key into single entries, but instead insert multiple entries for the same key (-> QMultiMap). Also, `unite` is (a) [marked obsolete](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap-obsolete.html#unite) in Qt 5.15 and removed in Qt 6.

Answer (score 1):

```
QVarianMap C(A); // copy-construct C from A
for (auto i = B.constBegin(); i != B.constEnd(); ++i)
{
     C.insert(i.key(), i.value()); // add B's element to C replacing C's entry with the same key if such exists
}
```

Comment: Close, but no cigar: this does `B.size()` lookups in a map that has size up to `A.size() + B.size()`, for a total cost of `O(#B log #(A+B))`. Instead, use the [insert overload](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#insertMulti-1) that takes an iterator into C as a "insertion hint", performing insertions in am. constant time, for a overall cost `O(#B)`.

Comment: @peppe Thank you for this improvement, I hope OP will catch it!

Comment: @peppe Just mentioned that your link points to insert**Multi**, which is not exactly what OP wants. The question asks for an insertion with existing key to replace value of existing C's entry, i.e. `insert` is required, but still your suggestion to use hint is useful

Comment: Sorry, wrong c&p (can't edit my previous comment)... anyhow, there's a `insert` overload as well: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#insert-1